# ANTLR: error recovery to not always match with the longest matched context

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I came across the following problem when I try to write a grammer for certain assembly lanuage.

The example grammar file looks like.

```
grammar test;
stat: operation+;
operation : (add | addi);


add : 'ADD' datatype  xd ',' xn;
addi : 'ADD.s64' xd ',' '#' imm;

datatype : '.s64'| '.f32';
xd : 'X0' | 'X1';
xn : 'X0' | 'X1';
imm : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4';
```

The grammar should be able to parser two assembly instruction

1. ADD: ex. ADD.s64 X1, X2 or ADD.f32 X1, X2
2. ADD(imm) ex. ADD.s64 X1, # X3

The problem is that because the add(imm) can only have the .s64 as the datatype.
I prefer not make a separate rule for datatype of ADD(imm).

However, when i enter ADD.s64 X1, X3, the parser always match with addi, and report the error "fail to match the #".

I guess it is because the logical of parser is to find the longest match of the text. (which is 'ADD.s64').

I am want to know is there a way, I can do error recovery so that it can then try to match the correct add rules?

Comment: How about `add32 : 'ADD.f32'  xd ',' xn;` and `add64 : 'ADD.s64' xd ',' (xn | '#' imm);`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In that case, I would rather add an immdatatye which only has .s64

Comment: The grammar you posted is not a valid ANTLR grammar: the comma in `'.s64', '.f32'` is invalid, and `imm : [0-9]+;` is not a valid parser rule (the `[...]` is only valid inside lexer rules). Perhaps you posted a scaled down version of your grammar and introduced some errors that are not present in your real grammar? It's always a good idea to post a grammar/code that can be copy+pasted so that others can reproduce the problem you're describing (which is not possible now).

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks. Let me edit my question

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `ADD.s64 X1, X3` cannot be matched, because xn cannot be equal to X3.

Because rule **add** is not matched, the parser tries to match rule **addi**, but fails because of character '#' that is not found in intruction.

By the way, the way you wrote your grammar, addi will match pattern like `ADD.s64 X1, # 3` and not `ADD.s64 X1, # X3`, as wanted